# Calling a class method from another class above it

Tags: python

I want to call a method_2 in the First class from the Second class from mehod_1 that was called from it.

See example code:

```
class First():
    def method_1(self):
        print("First method_1 runed")
        self.second = Second()
        self.second.method_1()

    def method_2(self):
        print("First - method_2 runed")

class Second():
    def method_1(self):
        first.method_2()

def main():
    first = First()
    **first.method_1()**

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

I tried searching on StackOwerflow and Google but couldn't find anything..

Everywhere they describe it the other way around...

Comment: You could pass `self` from `method_1` into `Second` so that each Second knows which  First it belongs to.

Comment: The fact that `Second.method_1` relies on the existence of a particular global variable should be a hint that you need to refactor a little bit.

Comment: [Humour] As a shaman I appreciate that you have your methods runed, code archeologists from the far future will better understand what this code was used for.  https://www.dictionary.com/browse/runed

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (as suggested in the comments), is to have `method_1` of the `Second` class take an argument, which will be a `First` object, which can then be passed to it within `First`'s `method_1`, e.g.:

```py
class First():
   def method_1(self):
       print("First method_1 runed")
       self.second = Second()

       # pass the instance of First (self) to Second's method_1
       self.second.method_1(self)

   def method_2(self):
       print("First - method_2 runed")


class Second():
   def method_1(self, first):
       # take an argument "first" that will be a First type object
       first.method_2()
```